# NSNotificationCenter notification fired twice on swipe

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

I am building an app with AVPlayer that will play songs from an api.

When a song ends, next song will be played. For this I am using the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playbackFinished:)
                                                 name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                               object:[_audioPlayer currentItem]];
}

-(void)playbackFinished:(NSNotification *)notification {
//    flagSkip = NO;
    NSLog(@"## %@ ", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
//    if(flagSkip == NO)
        [[DataSingleton sharedMySingleton] nextTrack];
//    else
//        flagSkip = NO;
}
```

On Swipe gesture, next song will be played.
For this, am removing the notification observer and adding it again as follows:

```
- (IBAction)skipButtonPressed:(id)sender
{

        [[DataSingleton sharedMySingleton] nextTrack];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:[_audioPlayer currentItem]];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(playbackFinished:)
                                                     name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                                   object:[_audioPlayer currentItem]];

    }else{
        //
    }
}
```

But when I swipe, sometimes the notification method gets called.

Where am I getting wrong? How do I solve this?

**Edit to include [[DataSingleton sharedMySingleton] nextTrack]**

```
    -(void)nextTrack{
    NSDictionary *prevTrackInfo; 
    if (currentIndex == -1){
        // We're at the start of a refilled list, so previousTrack should be 
        // the only thing in the cache dir. Clean it up.
        dispatch_queue_t removeFilesQueue;
        NSLog(@"## %@ removeFilesQueue", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));

        removeFilesQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.zombieprocess.removeFilesQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

        dispatch_sync(removeFilesQueue, ^{
            // Code goes here
            NSError *error = nil;
            [fileMgr removeItemAtPath:[self getFeedBandsCacheDir] error:&error];
            [fileMgr createDirectoryAtPath:[self getFeedBandsCacheDir] withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
        });

        //dispatch_release(removeFilesQueue);

    } else{
        if (trackInfo){
            prevTrackInfo = trackInfo;
        }else{
            NSLog(@"nextTrack, attempting to store prevTrackInfo, no trackInfo for currentIndex: %d", currentIndex);
        }
    }

    currentIndex += 1;

    // We should not have this, but just in case
    if (currentIndex >= self.feedEntries.count) {
        // We are at the end. Get the feed again.
        NSLog(@"## %@ currentIndex >= self.feedEntries.count", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
        if (self.feedEntries.count == 0) {
            [self loadFeed];
            return;
        }
        currentIndex = 0; // This will loop it back to the beginning
//        [self loadFeed];
//        return;
    }

    trackInfo = [self.feedEntries objectAtIndex:currentIndex];

    [self dispatchPlayNotification];

    if (prevTrackInfo && [self isTrackCached:prevTrackInfo] && prevTrackInfo != trackInfo && feedEntries.count > [self numberOfSongsToCache]){
        NSLog(@"nextTrack, deleting cached copy: %@", [[prevTrackInfo objectForKey:@"file_url"] lastPathComponent]);
        [self deleteCachedTrack:prevTrackInfo completionBlock:^{
            [self fillDownloadQueue];
        }];
    } else {
        [self fillDownloadQueue];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you've already switched the next song. So you can't remove notification observer with `[_audioPlayer currentItem]`, because it is already changed.

**Update 1.**

Try to replace 1st and 2nd lines:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:[_audioPlayer currentItem]];
[[DataSingleton sharedMySingleton] nextTrack];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playbackFinished:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:[_audioPlayer currentItem]];
```

Comment: did it, still the same

Comment: So post this method: `[[DataSingleton sharedMySingleton] nextTrack];`.

Comment: edited the method to include the same. Please check.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of removing the notification listener, I would read the current state on the player inside the method `(void)playbackFinished:(NSNotification *)notification`. 
For example:

```
- (IBAction)skipButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
      didSkipSong = YES;
      [[DataSingleton sharedMySingleton] nextTrack];

}
```

And in `-(void)playbackFinished:(NSNotification *)notification`

```
-(void)playbackFinished:(NSNotification *)notification {
  if(didSkipSong){
      didSkipSong = NO;
      return;
  }
  [[DataSingleton sharedMySingleton] nextTrack];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, man, your solution does not fix the problem, it just hides it for a while.

Comment: Why you say it does not fix the problem? I believe removing notification is a bad practice